# ¿Cómo puedo activar el GPS automáticamente en Android?

Tags: java, android, gps

Deseo activar el GPS, mi targetSdkVersion es 22 así que tengo los permisos al instalar la aplicación, como lo haría?

Comment: Puedes obtener información que ya se encuentra en el sitio sobre este tema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gps+android saludos!

Comment: en los temas de gps en android solo existe formas de obtener la latitude y longitude yo quiero de plano activar el GPS

Comment: Hasta donde se no se puede activar programaticamente, el usuario debe encenderlo tu debes verificar que no esté encendido y enviarlo a la pantalla de configuración de ubicación para que el mismo lo encienda

Answer (score 3):

Creo que directamente no se puede por seguridad.
Lo que normalmente se utiliza es llamar el cuadro de dialogo del sistema para activar el servicio de ubicación de las Google play services

Extraido de [Changing Location Settings](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html)

En la escucha de evento `OnFailureListener` al solicitar una ubicación con `FusedLocationProviderClient` ejemplo

```
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
...
task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
            // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
            // by showing the user a dialog.
            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Lo que ara es mostrar el siguiente cuadro de dialogo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]